# Can Power BI add range selection to a Line Chart?

Tags: powerbi

I'd like to build a report with power BI line chart. For there are too many values on the X-Axis, I was trying to add a range selection on the X-Axis like what [amChart does](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/).

So, I'm wondering if power BI can do this.

Also, I want to add hyperlink to each value on the X-Axis to link to related shared folder, is it doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time range selection, take a look at https://app.powerbi.com/visuals and try the Advanced Time Slicer visual.  It might already do what you're looking for.

For the x-axis urls, you have several approaches you can try.  The easiest approach is to have a related table in your report that shows the links. Then when a user selects a datapoint in your line chart, the table would update to show the relevant links.  Alternately you might try to extend the Power BI line chart with your own logic. This might be hard since Cartesian charts are more complex than other charts. You can find the line chart code here: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/src/Clients/Visuals/cartesian/lineChart.ts
Alternately you can just write your own purpose built visual that does exactly what you want.  This might actually be easier than extending the Power BI chart.  You can learn how to build your own visual by looking at our wiki: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/wiki

I was thinking about this more and wanted to mention one more solution. If you're looking to show the 'last n days' of data, instead of an arbitrary range, you can add a measure in DAX that returns the last days. I have an example here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukaszp/archive/2015/08/08/finding-the-latest-date-in-power-bi-desktop.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is really helpful for me.